# Password Generator must take all the selected attributes

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a password generator that can take four different attributes: uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers and symbols. It can create a password between 4-30 characters. All works well with the app except for one thing: I want to make sure that the generator includes all the attributes selected by the user. For example, if I were to create a 4-character-long password, the app may not include numbers or lowercase letter, etc. How can I include this logic to my code so that it will definitely include all the attributes selected by the user?

The solution was to pick one character from each selected attribute, then select the remaining attributes randomly, finally, shuffle the selected characters.

Here is my code that generates the password:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordLength: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uppercaseSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var lowercaseSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var symbolSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var lenghtChanged: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var generateButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    
    
    
    var length: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    var textField = UITextField()


   @IBAction func generateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let generatedPassword = fetchNewPassword()
        self.password = generatedPassword
        passwordField.text = password
    }


  func fetchNewPassword() -> String {
        
        password = ""
        passwordField.text = ""
        
        let passwordLength = Int(lengthChanged.value)
        
        if uppercaseSwitch.isOn {
            password += PasswordAttribute.uppercaseLetters.rawValue
        }
        if lowercaseSwitch.isOn {
            password += PasswordAttribute.lowercaseLetters.rawValue
        }
        if numberSwitch.isOn {
            password += PasswordAttribute.numbers.rawValue
        }
        if symbolSwitch.isOn {
            password += PasswordAttribute.symbols.rawValue
        }
        
        password = String((0..<passwordLenght).map {_ in password.randomElement()!})
        
        return password
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has very limited "entropy" (randomness.)

I guess your options meet the requirement (e.g. the password must contain a number and a symbol) but you ALWAYS only have one character of the specified type (upper case letter/lower case letter/number/symbol) and always in the same place.

I've built a password generator before, and I wrote it to first determine the set of legal symbols (upper case letter/lower case letter/number/symbol) and then generate the desired number of random characters from the specified list of legal types. That is much more random than what you're doing. (It's also harder for users to remember random strings of characters, but that's a separate issue.)

I took my design a step further, and allowed the user to specify different numbers of symbols and the types of allowed symbols in each group.

(e.g. Give me 1 upper case letter, then 3-6 lower-case letters, then 2 numeric digits, then a symbol, then 1 character that can by any of the above.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the user can select the attributes in the app I've built. I used switch buttons to select or unselect the attributes you want. If I use switch statements instead of if-else statement, would that make sure that all the attributes selected would be added to the password or should I just set the minimum character number to 8 or above so that it would have a higher change of adding the attributes selected?